# Imported a WordPress database to a new host now site doesn't show up

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bluehost

I made a site on one host (bluehost) and now the client wants it on another host (starlogic). Here is what I did:

1. Exported the database tables from bluehost and imported them into the database created on the starlogic server.
2. I replaced all of the old domain name references in the sql file with the new domain.
3. I installed the WordPress theme on the new starlogic server which was created on the old bluehost server.

Before I imported the old database info into the new database the site would show up (without any of the created pages or content of course). After I imported the database info I can get into the WordPress backend but when I go to view the actual site nothing shows up, just a blank white screen.

I am not sure what code if any would be helpful to see so just let me know and I was post it.

Comment: What error messages do you see in the Apache/PHP error logs?

Comment: I am not even sure where I would check this at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical fixes for a WP site white screen is to rename all theme folders except for twenty-ten to force the default theme or change the theme in admin; rename the plugins folder to force deactivate all plugins; reset permalinks; be sure you don't have any hardcoded URLs in the theme that you transferred.

If those don't work, and if you found/changed URLs in the DB with a text editor, try it again and use SQL queries in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. One more place you need to look at is:

```
current_theme
```

in export sql file. It pointed to a theme that doesn't exist in the new server.